# Why isn't the div called strip the same length as the two floated ones above

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

I am new to web design (as you can tell) and playing around with page layouts. I have build the following very basic fluid page that has two column divs (floats) and one div below that I want to set the width to match that of the two floated ones above. As you can see from the screen grab, the red 'strip' isn't as long.[image].

So basically what I have is 2 divs (`#main` and `#extras`) floated left. `#main` has a width of `65%` and `#extras` has a width of 20%. Main has a left and right margin of `3.666666666666667%` and `#extras` just a right `margin` of `3.666666666666667%` which centers it on the page pretty much. I also have `1% padding` for both `#main` and `#extras`.

I set the third div .strip (which should be exactly the same length as the #main and `#extras` combined as follows:

left/right margin 3.666666666666667%
2% padding (to equal the combined padding of the #main and #extras divs)
width: 85%

My calculations (although my math is terrible) makes that add up and as far as I can tell the third div #strip should be as long as the two above. But as from the picture, it isn't.

Is this something to do with a compounding effect?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
#header {
width: 100%;
background-color: gray;
margin: 0;

}

#main {
float: left;
width: 65%;
background-color: steelblue;
margin: 0 3.666666666666667%;
padding: 1%;
}

#extras {
float: left;
width: 20%;
background-color: orange;
margin: 0 3.666666666666667% 0 0;
padding: 1%;
}

#footer {
width: 100%;
clear: left;
background-color: gray;
margin-top: 5%;
}

.strip {
margin: 0 3.666666666666667%;
clear: left;
background-color: red;
padding: 2%;
width: 85%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">2 divs 
<p>Header</p>
</div>

<div id="main">
<p>Main content</p>
</div>

<div id="extras">
<p>Extra stuff</p>
</div>

<div class="strip">
</p>I am the strip</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<p>Footer</p>
</div>
</body>
ts</html>
```

Comment: Beside that your calculation is wrong due to the margin-right of `#main`, it's better to wrap all three container in another wrapper. This way you can set your width to 85% and margin simply to `margin: 0 auto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably wrong calculation.. You can understand this by seeing this image., where the extra margin adding up!

[image]

Comment: but the left margin on #extras is 0?

Comment: oh okie, still there's an extra 3.66 as u can see.. so the width of slider needs to be 103.66 by this way!

Comment: @Alan The margin to the left of `extras` is not `extra's` margin. As you say in your question `Main Content` has a left ***and*** right margin.

Comment: Got it... seemed so simple. Yes, just the extra margin on main gave it an extra length of 3.66 over the strip. Added that to the width of the strip and sorted... clouded head at the time is my excuse :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/manojmcet/LqLwx/)**:

**CSS**:

```
#main 
    {
float: left;
width: 65%;
background-color: steelblue;
margin-left: 3.666666666666667%;
padding: 1%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your margin is not set correctly, you have to explicitly specify right margins. Make it like this:

```
#main {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    background-color: steelblue;
    margin: 0 0 0 3.666666666666667%;
    padding: 1%;
}
```

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/wCWQL/**

Your earlier `css` was this:

```
margin: 0 3.666666666666667%;
```

This is a shorthand, where the first value is for `top` and `bottom` margins and the second value is for `right` and `left` margins.

So you have to explicitly specify all margins so that only the `left` one is set.

Alternatively, you can only set the `left` margin:

```
#main {
    margin-left: 3.666666666666667%;
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I intended to set both left and right margins for #main to 3.666666666666667%. That's why it is set as 0 (top and bottom) 3.666666666666667% (left and right) the #main has left and right set and therefore extras (which is to the right of the main) doesn't require a left margin, hense 0(top 3.666666666666667%(right) 0(bottom) 0(left). But thanks.... the issue is not making any sense to me!

Comment: @Alan: did you check the fiddle i provided? your `extras` div has `right` margin set with `left` margin as 0. but, you had `right` margin set on `main` div, which is the cause of the problem. you just need `left` margin on `main`, that's it.

Comment: yes but then it isn't 100% width, the main div has both L+R margin so the extras div only needs a right one?

Comment: @Alan: that is the problem in the first place! `main` div should *NOT* have both `left` and `right` margins. Only `left` margin. By the way, did you want to have them 100% in width?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the calculation. The first line width with values that you have add on properties is around 95.98% but the next lin (red div) the width is 88.86 %. Check the calcultions :)

Answer (score 0):

The two divs as the top have padding between them, their combined width without padding is 85%, you need to set the width of strip underneath to 85% + the width of the padding between the top divs.